# @ErrorPlace always getting shown

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I've been trying to figure out why mu web application is always responding the ErrorPresenter/ErrorView even the tokens are valid:

```
@Override
public void revealErrorPlace(String invalidStringToken) {
            GWT.log("Invalid token=" + invalidStringToken);
    revealPlace(errorPlaceRequest); 
}
```

For example I have defined in the NameTokens with static String variables: "main", "error", "map", "user"

However every time my application runs it goes to the #error page, even if I manually put the #main, #map, #user in the browser and the reavealErrorPlace shows that the tokens are invalid although it is properly registered with @NameTokens(NameTokens.user):

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@NameToken(NameTokens.user)
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<UserPresenter> {
}
```

When I try to manually access the #map and #user pages by appending these in the URL but still the presenter that is being displayed is the ErrorView and ErrorPresenter...

What could be causing this kind of behavior? I'm using GWT-Platform BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the places should be annotated with `#!map` instead of only `#map`.
Could that be the reason for the redirect to the error page?